# JS date format from mongoose date stamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, momentjs

I know similar questions has been asked many times but no answer is what I am looking for..

My code looks like this:

```
        <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">Date Requested
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Client
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Waybill
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">From
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">To
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Service
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Supplier
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">kg
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Supplier
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">VAT
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Total
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Client
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">VAT
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Total
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Profit
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Status
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Modify
                </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% for (let x of collections) {%>
                <tr style="<%= x.collectionStatusId.status == 'Requested' ? 'background-color: pink; color: black' : '' %>">
                    <td><%-x.createdAt%></td>
                    <td><%-x.client.companyName%></td>
                    <td><%-x.waybill%></td>
                    <td><%-x.sender.company%></td>
                    <td><%-x.receiver.company%></td>
                    <td><%-x.serviceId? x.serviceId.serviceCode : ''%></td>
                    <td><%-x.supplier? x.supplier.name : ''%></td>
                    <td><%-x.chargeableWeight%></td>
                    <td><%-x.supplierRate%></td>
                    <td><%-x.supplierVat%></td>
                    <td><%-x.supplierRate + x.supplierVat%></td>
                    <td><%-x.myRate%></td>
                    <td><%-x.myVat%></td>
                    <td><%-x.myRate + x.myVat%></td>
                    <td><%-(x.myRate - x.supplierRate)%></td>
                    <td><%-x.collectionStatusId.status%></td>
                    <td><a href="/admin/<%- x.collectionStatusId.status == 'Requested' ? 'accept' : 'edit' %>/<%- x.waybill %>"><%- x.collectionStatusId.status == 'Requested' ? 'Accept' : 'Update' %></a></td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">Date Requested
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Client
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Waybill
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">From
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">To
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Service
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Supplier
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">kg
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Supplier
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">VAT
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Total
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Client
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">VAT
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Total
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Profit
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Status
                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">Modify
                </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Focusing on this line:

```
<td><%-x.createdAt%></td>
```

Viewed in web it looks like this:

> Fri Sep 27 2019 17:38:08 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)

What I want it to look like:

> 27 Sep 2019

Using moment.js is this possible?

**What I've tried:**
At the top:

```
<script src="/js/moment.js"></script>
```

and then (hard-coded date for testing purposes)

```
<td><script>moment('1977-08-20 14:29:00 UTC').format('dd MMM YYYY')</script>   </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually am very new to JS and it took me a few minutes to figure it out but it was actually really simple..

```
<td><%-x.createdAt%></td>
```

was changed to

```
<td class="formattedDate"><%-x.createdAt%></td>
```

and at the bottom just before  the following was added:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('formattedDate');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML = moment(x[i].innerHTML).format('DD MMM YYYY');
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps